# sqlcmd how to run a query against specific database?

Tags: sql, sqlcmd

so this is the query that i want to run

```
sqlcmd -E -S localhost\MSSQLSERVER_2016 -i C:\Tables.sql
```

I have multiple databases in this instance and when the command above runs, i have no idea which database it runs the query against.
Is there any way that i can use sqlcmd to run against a database that i want it to run?

i have also tried

```
sqlcmd -E -S localhost\MSSQLSERVER_2016.mydatabase -i C:\Tables.sql
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `-d` command line option to specify your database.

[Link to the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

> **-d** *db_name*
>
> Issues a `USE` *db_name* statement when you start **sqlcmd**. This option sets the **sqlcmd** scripting variable SQLCMDDBNAME. This specifies the initial database. The default is your login's default-database property. If the database does not exist, an error message is generated and **sqlcmd** exits.

Comment: ah that did the trick... if only i read the documentation. Thank you!